# Is there a way to use a wildcard in a "where" statment for MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query that uses a where clause. At times, this may be used and at others, I may want to omit it completely to get back all results. I can certainly write two different queries but I would like to cut down on any code that I can for simplistic reasons. Is there a way to do this in mysql?

Take a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = '3'
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

Is there a way to use the top query and still get back all records?

Comment: where id <> 3 or id = 3; 
where id > 0;
where id is not null;

Comment: what are you actually trying to do , if you just lay down the scenario , people might be able to help you derive a better solution.

Comment: well that you are already doing with the first query, why u need the second one?

Comment: If I want to show the user ALL of the users on the system, how do you propose that I do that if there is a WHERE clause in the statement?

Comment: That my friend is not possible. Either you want all or you want specific , cant have it both ways. Cause you have specifically asked MySQL to give u records of id = 3 and that is exactly what it is giving you back, no more .. no less. 
However keeping in mind that when you get all the records , you will get the id = 3 record as well. So as someone suggested below , you can filter that in your code , that maybe aright for a few number of records but if its more than that then 2 queries are alot better.

Comment: Thanks Sabeen. That was what I figured. I just hate having to have a completely separate query minus the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More food for thought...

I notice you quoted the '3'.  If your ids are char data you could use the LIKE string comparison operator.

For a single value

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id LIKE '3'
```

For all values

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id LIKE '%'
```

Won't give you any values with NULL id though.

Comment: I will never have a null id so it's great.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the predicate in the first query may not actually retrieve all of the records from the table; it may use an index so that it only has to obtain the specific record(s) the query needs to return.

If you wanted to keep a predicate of that same form but still return all of the results, you would need to do something like this:

```
where id = 3 or id <> 3
```

or this:

```
where id = id
```

Note that to either of these, you'll have to add `or id is null` if `id` can be null.

If you just want to have a predicate in your query, this will suffice:

```
where 1
```

but this is just redundant, and you may as well just leave the predicate out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then YES

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: Thanks PAS. If I wanted to use "id" id='' how would I use this? I tried it just now but it returns nothing when it should return 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building the SQL query as you go along, and you decide *at the last minute* that you want to negate/ignore the "WHERE" part of your query, you can append `OR 1` to your where-clause.  Remember that logically, X OR TRUE is true for *all* X.

```
sqlite> SELECT id FROM moz_downloads WHERE id < 405 LIMIT 10;
80
403
404
sqlite> SELECT id FROM moz_downloads WHERE id < 405 OR 1 LIMIT 10;
80
403
404
405
407
408
409
410
411
412
```

Note that I had to stick a `LIMIT 10` in there to not get too many results for the demonstration, but the second statement's where-clause is `id < 405 or 1`.

It depends on the application, but you may or may not generate your queries at runtime.  Some queries will always be the same, like `SELECT * FROM recent_files`, but some queries will be like generated on-the-fly.  In the latter case, you might have something like

```
something = make_safe_for_sql(get_something_from_user())
query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE something=" + something
if should_ignore_something:
     query += " OR 1"
database.execute(query)
```

<sub>Note: Depending on your SQL engine, you might need to do `OR 1=1` to evaluate to a boolean true.</sub>

Comment: Hi Mark. This query is already built and wouldn't be written at "the last minute". What throws me about your query is that your second query is missing the "OR 1". I'm not following how I would "dynamically" insert the "OR 1" when I need it. Am I making sense?

Comment: Hey Mark, I tried this and at least I didn't get any errors. WHat I am getting is all rows even when I put in a valid user_id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Jim, the `OR 1` *forces* the query to return all of the rows, regardless of the rest of the where-clause.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Hey Mark, yes that's what I wanted but it wouldn't work. I was getting all rows regardless of whether the id was null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is dubious. You are really saying that when there is no `id==3` all entries should be returned. You can do that easily if you pull all entries and then sort them out using php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) {
    if($row['id']==3)
        // do something
}
```

But as the table grows this will put an enormous stress on the database. You should go with the multiple query and enforce some kind of limit on the second query.

```
// try to get id == 3
SELECT * FROM my_table

// if id == 3 returns 0 results
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 5
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to be using dynamic SQL, like

> "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id " &
>   qualifier

Then set qualifier to "= '3'" or to "1".

Comment: Hi Lance. Can you tell me if I have to use a stored procedure for this or can I use a regular sql statement?

Comment: @Jim: You'd want to look into MySQL's PreparedStatement for dynamic SQL on MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html

Comment: Thank you for that link rexem. I'll have a look now.